# Grails One-To-Many unidirectional without join table is it possible?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Grails One-To-Many unidirectional without creating join table is not working. I tried as per Documentation mentioned [here](http://people.apache.org/%7Epledbrook/grails-guide/guide/single.html#5.5.2%20Custom%20ORM%20Mapping).

When I tried creating an Domain class as per the documentation its creating the Join Table. Is this a bug or my understanding is wrong?. Here is the code which I used

```
class Person {
    String bookName
    static hasMany = [addresses: Address]
    static mapping = {
        addresses column: 'person_address_id'
    }
 }

 class Address {
    String address
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And the resulting table EER Model is

[image]

**NOTE:** Using datasource.dbCreate as "create-drop" in application.yml file.

Comment: From your description it is not clear what is the correct relation? You clearly say that Book has many authors, is it correct? One author, I think, may write more then one book... so it's Many-To-Many. One-To-Many would be if you simplified the task saying that one book always has one and only author.

Comment: @AndrejIstomin I have updated my question for your better understanding. Is it possible for you to explain now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unidirectional mapping w/o join table is only possible, if you invert the relation between your domain classes:

```
class Person {}

class Address {
  static belongsTo = [ person:Person ]
}
```

I usually go that way, as it has the better performance and consistency comparing to others.

The only thing which is missing out-of-box is `give me all addresses for person`-case, which can be modelled relatively easy:

```
class Person {

  List<Address> getAddresses( params = [:] ) {
    Address.findAllByPerson this, params
  }

}
```

Comment: Make sense. So we can conclude that unidirectional mapping w/o Join table from Person to Address is not available right ?

Comment: the join table is not needed at all in my case. Each Address-record will have a foreign-key column to Person-record

Comment: Crisp and clear